# How to call a WINAPI function with ctypes and store the return value

Tags: python-2.7, winapi, ctypes

I read the ctypes docs and a couple of tutorials, but I still don't understand a few things.

1. Does `ctypes.wintypes` define Windows types such as `HANDLE`?
2. How would I call, for example, `NtQueryInformationProcess`, which returns an `NTSTATUS` value, and store the return value?
3. How can I dereference a pointer to walk the `PEB` structure using ctypes?

Sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: If found this [ntdll.py](https://github.com/MarioVilas/winappdbg/blob/master/winappdbg/win32/ntdll.py) that wraps [`NtQueryInformationProcess`](https://github.com/MarioVilas/winappdbg/blob/master/winappdbg/win32/ntdll.py#L418) among others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `HANDLE` is actually a pointer, so using `ctypes.c_void_p` will be enough.
2. You call it via `ctypes.windll.ntdll.NtQueryInformationProcess` like any other function in Python, but passing C objects (such as `ctypes.c_int`) as arguments. `NTSTATUS` is not a structure but a long. However, you can create [C-like structures using `ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) if you need.
3. See *Pointers* in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#pointers).

You might want to check out [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/), a higher-level and more *pythonic* interface for the Windows API, although it's not completely covered.

Hope it helps!

Comment: (1) Using the Windows type aliases, such as `wintypes.HANDLE`, is clearer for someone who has experience with Windows programming. (2) Please use `ctypes.WinDLL('ntdll')` instead of `ctypes.windll.ntdll`. The `windll` loader has troublesome function-pointer caching. (3) Jake  is interested in native NT programming to call [`NtQueryInformationProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684280) to get the [`PEB`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa813706), so PyWin32 won't be of any help.

Comment: Hey thank @eryksun. can you hekp me with another one pls ? when im issuing NtQueryInformationProcess with PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION. How do i cast the returned buffer "PebBaseAddress" to a PEB structure so i can access its members ?