# How to prevent screen recording in python

Tags: python

After searching for hours, I have no choice left to ask some python gurus. I want to prevent a user to capture my app windows, that is built in python.

I'm currently using **tinker**. I'm also aware of the C# but I want to do it in python. Here is a reference of C# [How can i prevent screen recording using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351709/how-can-i-prevent-screen-recording-using-c-sharp).

I hope there will be `SetwindowDisplayAffinity` alternative in python. Your reply will be appreciated.

Please note I'm currently new to python.

Answer (score 0):

[`SetwindowDisplayAffinity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity) is a WinAPI function :

```cpp
BOOL SetWindowDisplayAffinity(
  [in] HWND  hWnd, // A handle to the top-level window.
  [in] DWORD dwAffinity  /* The display affinity setting that specifies where 
                            the content of the window can be displayed.*/
);
```

The `dwAffinity` value you want is `WDA_MONITOR` (hex=`0x00000001`), so that part is not too difficult.
As for `hWnd`, the *window handler*, there is already answers for that : [How to get the HWND of a Tkinter window on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218662/how-to-get-the-hwnd-of-a-tkinter-window-on-windows) or [Getting tkinter current window handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70500016/getting-tkinter-current-window-handle).
Now there's only to call that function : [How to use Win32 API with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025029/how-to-use-win32-api-with-python).
I'm not sure you will be able to call `win32api.SetWindowDisplayAffinity` after having `pip install`ed `pywin32`, so in last resort you can use `ctypes` like in [How to call a WINAPI function with ctypes and store the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093690/how-to-call-a-winapi-function-with-ctypes-and-store-the-return-value).